# ECDSA hash from OpenSSL command-line

Tags: openssl, hash

Although it seems relatively easy to build an ECDSA hash programmatically, I've exhaustively searched for how to do it via command-line (in order to validate my results), and have found no examples of how to do it via the command-line.

Does anyone have experience with this?